# C function to find lines that differ from each other

Tags: c

I am trying to implement the function that compares two files. The function should restore the first lines that differ from each other. If the files are the same, NULL will be returned. The function ends as soon as either of the files ends, and then NULL is returned. I think my if functions doesn't work and so on this function don't return the lines.

Here is my code:

```
char *difference(const char* file1, const char* file2)
{
    char line1[1000];
    char line2[1000];
    char *a = malloc(1000 * sizeof(char));

    FILE *f1 = fopen(file1, "r");
    FILE *f2 = fopen(file2, "r");
    if (!f1 || !f2) // checking if there is any error 
    {
        return -1; 
    }

    while (fgets(line1, sizeof(line1), file1) != NULL && fgets(line2, sizeof(line2), file1) != NULL)
{
    if (strcmp(line1, line2) != 0)
    {
        strcpy(a, line1);
        strcpy(a, line2);

    }
    else
    {
        return NULL;
    }
}

fclose(f1);
fclose(f2);
return a;

int main(void)

    char* diff = difference("testifile.c", "testifile2.c");
    printf("\n--- Difference:\n");
    printf("%s", diff);

    free(diff);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Tip: Don't sprinkle numbers like `1000` through your code, instead `#define` a constant or have a variable that defines this.

Comment: The function instantiation at the point of the first `return` ceases so you aren't actually returning both lines with `return puts(line1);` followed by `return puts(line2);`

Comment: It makes no sense to return `puts(line1)`, and it makes even sense to try to return `puts(line2)` afterwards.

Comment: @bigwillydos And `puts` doesn't return lines anyway.

Comment: Is the function supposed to return the first line from the first file that differs, or from the second file, or both?

Comment: @SteveSummit yep, but he's new here tho and likely new to C programming so figured I'd just comment on what I saw as the bigger misconception between those two

Comment: @SteveSummit The function is supposed to return both lines

Comment: Check what `fgets` returns... It doesn't return `EOF` ever. Doesn't your compiler give you a warning? Turn on warnings (`-Wall -Wextra` is good for *gcc* and *clang*, for example) and *fix them* as first step.

Comment: "return," you keep using that word. I do not think it means what you think it means. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/return

Comment: @L0KiZ When you say the function is supposed to return both lines, did you mean it is supposed to print out both lines?

Comment: @SteveSummit Yes, for example if in file1 contains text: "Hello" and for file2 "Hi". Program should print "Hello" -- "Hi".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah that doesn't work so good. Here are the bugs:

```
return -1;
```

Does not compile. Did you mean

```
return (char*)-1;
```

Also, leaks memory. Do:

```
 if (f1) fclose(f1);
 if (f2) fclose(f2);
 return (char*)-1;
```

Oops you read from `file1` twice:

```
while (fgets(line1, sizeof(line1), file1) != NULL && fgets(line2, sizeof(line2), file1) != NULL)
```

should be

```
while (fgets(line1, sizeof(line1), file1) != NULL && fgets(line2, sizeof(line2), file2) != NULL)
```

Memory trashing:

```
line3=strcat(line1,line2);
```

Should be:

```
strcat(strcpy(a,line1),line2);
```

Only ever checks first line because early return:

```
else
{
    return NULL;
}
```

Just eliminate that block.

Oops forgot to check for errors:

```
char* diff = difference("testifile.c", "testifile2.c");

char* diff = difference("testifile.c", "testifile2.c");
if (diff == (char *)-1) {
    /* handle file open error */
}
else if (diff == NULL) {
    /* handle no difference */
}
else {
     /* your message */
     free(diff);
}
```